# How to convert .tif image to .jpg using skimage

Tags: python, scikit-image

I'm trying to convert a .tif image in python using the module skimage.
It's not working properly.

```
from skimage import io
img = io.imread('/content/IMG_0007_4.tif')
io.imsave('/content/img.jpg', img)
```

Here is the error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/imageio/core/functions.py in get_writer(uri, format, mode, **kwargs)
 if format is None:
   raise ValueError(
     "Could not find a format to write the specified file " "in mode %r" % mode)

ValueError: Could not find a format to write the specified file in mode 'i'
```

EDIT 1:

A method I found to do this was to open using skimage, convert it to 8bits and then save it as png. 
Anyway I can't save it as .jpg

```
img = io.imread('/content/IMG_0007_4.tif',as_gray=True)
img8 = (img/256).astype('uint8')
matplotlib.image.imsave('/content/name.png', img8)
```

Comment: There's already a question about saving jpg images using sklearn. This isn't a duplicate, but you may be able to find your answer on how to achieve your results here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361966/scikit-image-write-a-ndarray-to-image-with-imsave-read-back-with-imread-data

Comment: Please also provide the test image, so that we can see if there is anything special about this specific file.

Comment: Does the TIF have either layers or pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good tool called ImageMagick it can be installed in linux.
To call it inside python code i just did this.

```
os.system("convert image.png -colorspace RGB image.jpg ")
```

Comment: You can use Python Wand, which uses ImageMagick, if you do not want to use os.system. See http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.7

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided an image plugin in the save command. See https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.io.html#skimage.io.imsave where it says:

> When saving a JPEG, the compression ratio may be controlled using the
>   quality keyword argument which is an integer with values in [1, 100]
>   where 1 is worst quality and smallest file size, and 100 is best
>   quality and largest file size (default 75). This is only available
>   when using the PIL and imageio plugins.